# Updating a column from the results of a counting subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have the following query:

```
SELECT count(distinct document_key), etl_telco_cycle.customer_number FROM telco_document_header inner join etl_telco_cycle on  (telco_document_header.customer_number like '%' || etl_telco_cycle.customer_number) where telco_document_header.document_cycle = substring(cast(now() - interval '1 month' as varchar) from 1 for 4) || substring(cast(now() - interval '1 month' as varchar) from 6 for 2) and telco_document_header.customer_number like '%' || etl_telco_cycle.customer_number) group by etl_telco_cycle.customer_number
```

which returns this:

[image: Result:]

Now I want to use that result to update count in a table where `customer_number` match. I tried this:

```
update etl_telco_cycle set amount_mobilephone_numbers = (SELECT count(distinct document_key), etl_telco_cycle.customer_number FROM telco_document_header inner join etl_telco_cycle on  (telco_document_header.customer_number like '%' || etl_telco_cycle.customer_number) where telco_document_header.document_cycle = substring(cast(now() - interval '1 month' as varchar) from 1 for 4) || substring(cast(now() - interval '1 month' as varchar) from 6 for 2) group by etl_telco_cycle.customer_number)
```

which results in this:

[image: Error:]

Comment: Please remember to always disclose your version of Postgres. And for data and error messages we very much prefer text over screenshots.

Comment: Will do next time. thx und schönes Wochenende!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a correlated subquery:

```
update etl_telco_cycle
    set amount_mobilephone_numbers = (SELECT count(distinct document_key)
                                      FROM telco_document_header tdh
                                      WHERE tdh.customer_number = etl_telco_cycle.customer_number AND 
                                            tdh.document_cycle = substring(cast(now() - interval '1 month' as varchar) from 1 for 4) || substring(cast(now() - interval '1 month' as varchar) from 6 for 2) 
                                    );
```

I'm not sure why your version uses `LIKE` for the match on customer numbers.  That seems awkward, so I removed it.

I also think the date logic can be written more concisely using `TO_CHAR()`:

```
update etl_telco_cycle
    set amount_mobilephone_numbers = (SELECT count(distinct document_key)
                                      FROM telco_document_header tdh
                                      WHERE tdh.customer_number = etl_telco_cycle.customer_number AND 
                                            tdh.document_cycle = TO_CHAR(now() - interval '1 month', 'YYYYDD')
                                     );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`FROM` clause to the `UPDATE` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html):

```
UPDATE etl_telco_cycle e
SET    amount_mobilephone_numbers = c.ct
FROM  (
   SELECT e.customer_number, count(distinct document_key) AS ct
   FROM   telco_document_header t
   JOIN   etl_telco_cycle       e ON  t.customer_number like '%' || e.customer_number
   WHERE  t.document_cycle = substring(cast(now() - interval '1 month' as varchar) from 1 for 4)
                          || substring(cast(now() - interval '1 month' as varchar) from 6 for 2)
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) c
WHERE e.customer_number = c.customer_number
AND   e.amount_mobilephone_numbers IS DISTINCT FROM c.ct;  --optional optimization
```

While you can also use a correlated subquery, this would typically be much slower, running one aggregation query per target row, while this query runs a *single* aggregation query. And there is a minor difference: if no related rows are found in a correlated subquery like [Gordon demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53193919/939860), the column is still updated to NULL (which would fail for columns defined `NOT NULL`), while my query does *nothing* instead (keeping the old value). You'll have to define the desired behavior.

The added `AND e.amount_mobilephone_numbers IS DISTINCT FROM c.ct` prevents empty updates. Related:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

You could optimize the performance of the counting subquery some more. You may not need `DISTINCT` nor the `JOIN` in the subquery - would need to see exact table definitions and constraits. Looks like you can replace this either way:

```
   substring(cast(now() - interval '1 month' as varchar) from 1 for 4)
|| substring(cast(now() - interval '1 month' as varchar) from 6 for 2)
```

with:

```
to_char(now() - interval '1 month', 'YYYYMM')
```

Either depends on the current `timezone` setting, which may be undesirable in corner cases.

And `document_cycle` should be a `date` or `integer`, not a string type ...

Comment: @HeikoO: Note the additions.